# Why is my Analog Input channel adding voltage to my signal?

Tags: arduino-mega, analogread, voltage

*EDIT*: Here are the links to the sensor spec sheet (http://www.omega.com/temperature/pdf/HX71.pdf) and manual (http://www.omega.com/Manuals/manualpdf/M4543.pdf) for your reference.

I'm using a relative humidity (RH) sensor with an Arduino Mega. The RH sensor runs off of +/- 24V  (which is being sourced by a power supply), and outputs a signal from 0-5VDC. Naturally, I am plugging this output signal into my A0 channel. There is a bare Earth Ground wire that is wired to the power supply's earth ground (possible error?) **Arduino's GND is connected to the power supply's EARTH GND, fyi**.

I compared the voltage reading in my Arduino Serial Monitor to a reliable Fluke multimeter, and **the analog input channel is adding ~.2 Volts!**

From some research, I have read about "high impedance" "source impedance" "internal wiring of Arduino" etc, but unfortunately I am failing to grasp the reason *why* this is happening. I'd like to know so then I could figure out a solution on my own.

Below is a schematic of what I'm dealing with so that it may better illustrate my issue (also my code). Thank you for your time, and I appreciate your help!

[image: Error drawn out.])

```
void setup() 
{

Serial.begin(9600);

} 

void loop() 
 {

  float hs1 = ((( analogRead(A0) * ( 5.0 / 1024.0) ) )* 20.0 ); 

  Serial.print("RH%");
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(hs1);
  Serial.print(";");  
  Serial.println(); 
  delay(1000); 

}
```

Comment: Link to the RH sensor data sheet?

Comment: Oh yes! here's the spec sheet: http://www.omega.com/temperature/pdf/HX71.pdf and the manual http://www.omega.com/Manuals/manualpdf/M4543.pdf

Comment: I'm using model HX71-V1, thank you @Majenko

Comment: One of the biggest mistakes people make when calculating the voltage of an ADC is they assume the chip is running at 5.000000 volts. Have you measured the 5V pin of the Arduino with your Fluke?

Comment: How do you know your fluke is accurate ? :). You could measure the 5v using A1 and 'calibrate' your reading on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you guys are gonna get a KICK out of this!

The analog input channel was **not** adding millivolts to my Analog Input signal. I stupidly was not supplying my Arduino Mega with 9V!! I had it running off of the USB port, which was affecting my 5V reference (thank you @majenko for pointing that out!).

I measured the 5V pin and it was fluctuating between 4.41-4.21 volts. My colleague made a comment and I reviewed the Arduino Mega datasheet. It must be supplied with 7-12 volts in order for the 5V to output correctly.

Once I hooked my Power Vin + GND to my power supply, set that at 9V/.08amps my analog input readings were accurate.

**Thank you everyone for your help!**